# using bootstrap and having a weird background issue before container div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap 2.3.2 to create my website, it seems like a simple problem and i have spent hours but couldn't fix it. i have added a background colour div before the container div, it does work fine but on resizing browser bg div width start to hide itself from the right side.

i tried using container-fluid but it stretches everything to left and right.

i am not using a responsive layout.

here is my code

```
<div class="bg">
<div class="container">
<p> Test content goes here </p>
</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
<style>
.bg {
    background:#0C9;
}
</style>
```

looking for help

Comment: Why not apply the background directly to `.container`? The code you gave performs exactly as it's supposed to, try providing more?

Comment: because it's already been used throughout the website, it gonna effect all of them

Comment: Even though this is not related to your question I suggest you to use BootStrap 3. It's great.

Comment: @celleyes But I'm saying add the `bg` class to the same element as `container`. It'd be `<div class="container bg">`

Comment: thanks for helping , after applying class="container bg" , background only within the container but not the outside of container.

Comment: the thing is that, i need a flawless continues background on top , middle and footer , three different backgrounds, outside of their containers. i even tried that on boostrap 3 but same issue